# Why is my web scraper not affected by changes in the steam URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I built this web scraper to scrape steam for item names and their lowest price. It works, but it only scrapes the first page (which is fine, I'm working on that). But what is interesting is that when I change the url http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q= to be http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=#p2 (which is the url for the second page of items), I get the exact same output, which is the items from the first page. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_num = 1

url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q='
open_url = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
market_page = BeautifulSoup(open_url)

for i in market_page('div', {'class' : 'market_listing_row      market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult'}):
    item_name = i.find_all('span', {'class' : 'market_listing_item_name'})[0].get_text()
    price = i.find_all('span')[1].get_text()
    page_num += 1
    print  item_name + ' costs ' + price
```

Comment: is `url` in your code just missing the 'q=' or is that how you call it?

Comment: Oh it's not missing that's just a typo on this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inspect the REST calls that the page makes using Chrome or Firefox. It looks like the correct end points and parameters are something like this:

http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?query=&start=10&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=quantity&sort_dir=desc

Comment: How would I go about inspecting the REST calls?

Comment: If you bring up the developer tools. Should be F12. Go to the networking tab. Then refresh the page or go to a url and you should see all of the requests made to the server.